# MSXML : Javascript is not a scripting language

Tags: javascript, xml, vbscript, xslt-1.0, msxml

I have installed in my pc MSXML 2.6 MSXML 3.0 MSXML 4.0 MSXML 6.0

when i try to parse my XSL in execution time i have the error : 
Error -2147467259 Javascript is not a scripting language

My code:

```
Set ObjXMLTransformDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.5.0")

ObjXMLTransformDoc.Load (mResultPath & MyDocument.DOC_TYPE & "_XML_TO_XSL.xml")

Set ObjXMLTransformStyle = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.5.0")
ObjXMLTransformStyle.Load ActiveWorkbook.path & "\RESULT\form_generation.xsl"
ObjXMLTransformStyle.setProperty "AllowXsltScript", True

Set ObjXMLStyle = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.5.0")
ObjXMLTransformDoc.transformNodetoObject ObjXMLTransformStyle, ObjXMLStyle
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What filename are you using for the script?  JS, VBS, WSF?

Comment: Brilliant error message: I'm sure some Javascript enthusiasts would agree with the statement. My guess is your XSLT contains an msxsl:script element with incorrect language code.

Comment: I presume you have some reason to use VBScript and MSXML instead of .NET?

Comment: Show the XSL file.  It's likely there is some script there.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks like VisualBasic script to me.  I believe you will need to make sure your file has a `.vbs` extension, not `.js`.  The big giveaway is using Set instead of the var keyword used by J[ava]Script.  Also, the generous use of ampersand helps.

Comment: On a second pass, I wonder if you are referring to code embedded inside your XSLT and not the script you posted.  If that's the case, it'd be helpful to see that code instead.